# Quickfix setting ResetSeqNumFlag

Tags: java, quickfix, quickfixj

Is there a way to set `ResetSeqNumFlag=Y` using the Quickfix config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the "Miscellaneous" section of the manual:

http://www.quickfixj.org/quickfixj/usermanual/1.5.1/usage/configuration.html

There are several reset options (Logon/Logout/Disconnect/Error etc.)

Comment: Still dont get why there isnt a simple ResetSeqNumFlag option...ResetOnLogon didnt seem to do this but I set all the options to Y and it seemed to set the flag.

Answer (score 2):

As I know there is no way to do it.

I had a situation when after logon I got logout message with the text

```
MsgSeqNum too low, expecting 194 but received 16 Logon
```

I have looked through the manual and played with reset options in config:

```
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
ResetOnError=Y
```

None of them adds `ResetSeqNumFlag=Y` to logon message. So I had to do it manually at `#toAdmin` method.

Comment: What was the StartTime and EndTime of your counterparty? Normally if the two parties (you & counterparty) have these same settings, a hard reset of sequence numbers isn't necessary. Both just do it under the hood and will have reset sequence numbers when logging on at StartTime. I.e. none of the `ResetOnXXX` would have to be set in that case.

Comment: I think that could be the reason. I set wrong times before. To check if hard reset is not necessary I need to wait to tomorrow

Comment: Make sure your time zone is set correctly in your settings along with your start/end time.

Comment: I did it as well